# Terminal not displaying UTF-8 character(s)

Tags: bash, bashrc

I have changed my `bash` prompt in `~/.bashrc` and have verified my character encoding is set to UTF-8. I am using the monospace font and Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is my `~/.bashrc`
http://pastebin.com/009K2Kd6

This is what I am getting for the black right triangle:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post your `PS1=` line from `~/.bashrc`, obviously there's something wrong there.

Comment: @kos Updated OP.

Comment: Works for me in `gnome-terminal`. Is that `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: It breaks in the same way in `xterm` though. I suppose that's what you're using?

Comment: @kos It's gnome terminal. I almost want to reset my entire gnome-terminal since I've done some heavy modification over the past year. I'll probably start there and come back to this, especially if it's working for you and not me.

Comment: Maybe check that Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Compatibility -> Encoding is set to UTF-8: changing that (pretty obviously) breaks the prompt for me.

Comment: What happens if you unset `TERM` variable ?

Comment: @kos Figured it out. Not a "solution" per say but an alternative. Seems to be working flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that get that strange invalid unicode character for the arrow, edit the following line:

```
local BRPT=$(echo -e "\xee\x82\xb0")        #UTF 8 Black Right pointing triangle
```

All is right with the world now. Also, fonts that go well with this can be found at [powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Glad that you're happy with this solution, but this doesn't really solve the problem, it just circumvents it: `\xe2\xae\x80` should be printed.

Comment: @kos Just out of curiosity, what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm on 15.04. Have you tried just to purge / reinstall `gnome-terminal` by the way? Ah, and if you want to make a comparison I have GNOME Terminal 3.14.2

Comment: @kos Yup. Tried that originally but didn't work.

Comment: @kos Upgrading to 15.04. Lets see how this works.

Comment: @kos Same result. This time it's displaying two arrows rather than the box with the unicode code in the OP screenshot.

Comment: Isn't that the expected result? `\xe2\xae\x80` is the hex sequence for that character: http://unicode-table.com/en/2B80/, what were you expecting?